# JS files getting executed itself when added to web-resource in JIRA

Tags: javascript, jira

I'm developing a Jira plugin and came through the below problem.
I have 2 js files a.js and b.js added to web-resource mapping in atlassin-plugin.xml. Initially the JavaScript of a.js was in a.vm file and JavaScript of b.js was in b.vm file. I thought to add the JavaSrcipts into seperate JS files and link them to vm files.

And when I run the app and do a button click which should only trigger a.js, I could see that JavaScript in b.js also got executed. But when I add the content of b.js back to b.vm file and remove b.js from web-resource mapping, it didn't get executed unnecessarily. I have mapped the .js files in in atlassin-plugin.xml as below.

```
<web-resource key="resourceKey" name="Resources" >   
    <description>JavaScript</description>
    <resource type="download" name="a.js" location="js/a.js" />
    <resource type="download" name="b.js" location="js/a.js" />
    <context>jira.admin</context>
</web-resource>
```

And called it in both the .vm files as below:

```
$webResourceManager.requireResource("plugginKey123:resourceKey")
```

The content of b.js is simply something like below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {                                                
    alert("inside b.js!");  
});
```

What could have gone wrong or have I missed something? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You mentioned that the contents of b.js get executed "unnecessarily", but what you included above in `b.js` is a function that gets invoked on DOM ready, so it should *always* get executed whenever a page includes that .js file. Can you post the actual code segments from your .js files, and also explain the mechanism by which you expect each piece of JS to get invoked?

Comment: Also, you wrote `<resource type="download" name="b.js" location="js/a.js" />`. I think you meant for the `location` attribute on this line to point to `js/b.js`.